# Cambio de tamaño de imagen después de subir la web

Tags: html, css, html5, web, vscode

Tengo un código en *HTML5* y *CSS* para una web, cuando hago la prueba de la web de modo local (en mi pc) respeta lo indicado lo colocado en CSS, luego cuando subo y la visualizo en internet (Web) no respeta lo indicado en el archivo `.css`, quiero saber que pasa; adjunto el código creado en *CSS* . NO SOLO ES EL ENCABEZADO, SINO TODA PAGINA.

**HTML**

```
<header class="encabezado_general">
        <nav>
            <a href="">Inicio</a>
            <a href="">Publicaciones</a>
            <a href="">Descargas</a>
            <a href="">Muro</a>
            <a href="">Acerca de</a>
        </nav>
        <section class="frase_enca">
            <h1>Bienvenido a GeoFault</h1>
            <h2>Buenas publicaciones</h2>
        </section>
        <div class="ola_img_enca" style="height: 150px; overflow: hidden;" ><svg viewBox="0 0 500 150" 
            preserveAspectRatio="none" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
            <path d="M0.00,49.99 C160.46,143.58 349.21,-49.99 500.00,49.99 L500.00,150.00 L0.00,150.00 Z" 
            style="stroke: none; fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></path></svg></div>
</header>
```

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background: #603813;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #b29f9473, #6038136c), url(../img/enca_1.jpg);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #b29f9473, #6038136c), url(../img/enca_1.jpg); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: relative;
```

Asimismo, este es lo que me aparece cuando inspecciono la web:
[image]

Como se muestra en el `height:700px` se cambia en la web a `height:650px`

Comment: Ayudaría mucho anexes detalles tales como: ¿usas algún framework?, ¿podrías agregar tu HTML completo para poder reproducir tu escenario y ver completo el fallo?

Comment: No utilizo ningún framework. Ahora cargo el código html.

Comment: Puede ser un problema tan tonto como la caché. ?Has probado `Ctrl + F5` para que refresque la caché?

Comment: esta bien, gracias...